# Trying to draw rib tangent to a circle AutoCad 3d modeling

Tags: design, cad, technical-drawing, autocad

I'm trying to draw a rib tangent to a circle but If some one can link a video or a tutorial on how to do that I'd be really thankful here's the drawing in 2d (the rib is highlighted with the red circle) .

### [image: []]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the rib stand proud.  ie make it extend so it greater than the diameters of the circles.
2. Make a cone that has the same base diameter as the circle at the base of the rib.  If you need the tip of the cone, draw a line through the same relative point on the large and small circle.  Project this line to the axis of the circles and this is the location of the tip of the cone.
3. You have a few options for how to proceed from here. one is to take the intersection of the rib and the cone.  Another is to draw a cube the encompasses the cone and then subtract the cone from the cube.  You can now use the cone to subtract the excess material from the ribs